# CVE-2020-1472 vs Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008

Trying to secure some old servers. We do have an upgrade path, just that the replacements are being tested with the rest of the new system and may not be available for many months.

I have Windows Server 2008 (x86, not R2) on the domain controllers and trying to secure against the CVE-2020-1472 vulnerability.

There is a patch for Server 2008 R2, via extended support (KB4571729).
Is there a patch available, even via extended support, for 2008 x86 servers?

Comment: Server 2008 R2 is based on Windows 7 this has extended support, Server 2008 is based on Vista, which does not have extended support.  Best take the unsupported versions out of commission as quickly as possible.  **Server 2008 hasn’t been supported or patch in years.**

Comment: Ah, that explains a lot @Ramhound. Stick it as an answer and I'll accept it.
And we are binning the old ones soon, just not soon enough.

Comment: While indeed based on Vista, my comment was partially incorrect, ESU for Sever 2008 is available.  However, it doesn’t appear, Microsoft patch 2008 (yet).  2008 and 2008/R2 extended support both ended in Jan 2020 on the same date

Comment: Microsoft makes it clear by omission that 2008 will remain unpatched.  [They only released a patch for 2008R2 SP1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4557222/how-to-manage-the-changes-in-netlogon-secure-channel-connections-assoc)